# how to edit node-red static content in bluemix node red editor?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, static-content

When you create a node-red application in bluemix,  the intro page says

`The page you are reading now is served as static content from the application. This can be replaced with whatever content you want in the public directory.`

I can't see anywhere in the bluemix UI or node red editor to add/edit static content.  How do I edit static content for the node-red app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly from Bluemix (or Node-RED) but you should be able to enable the continuous delivery pipeline.

This should create a copy of the deployed app in a git repository that you can then edit with a Eclipes Orion based web editor.

There should be a link on the app page in the Bluemix console to enable this. From memory it's in the lower right hand corner of the summary page iirc.